# How is it possible, to open several pictures with imagej?

Tags: java, imagej

I want to open pictures with the help of imagej by **choosing** them in one of my folders. Right now I have this one as a compromise but it is not cool at all:

```
            Opener fo = new Opener();
            DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser("testchooser");
            String string = dc.getDirectory();
            for(int j=1;j<4;j++){
                for(int i =1; i<14; i++){
                    imgPlus = new ImagePlus();
                    if(i<10){
                        imgPlus = fo.openImage(string + "1." + j + ".0" + i + ".tiff");  
                    } else{
                        imgPlus = fo.openImage(string + "1." + j + "." + i + ".tiff");  
                    }
                    try{
                    ip = (ImageProcessor) imgPlus.getProcessor();
                    } catch(NullPointerException e1){
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

My pictures are numbered by this scheme 1.1.01 - 1.3.13 (as you see in the code) and I gotta chose the folder in which they are to find. Of course it is not optimal at all when I put the names hard into the code, so I would be thankful for any advice. 
Thanks!

Comment: Don't know about ImageJ strategies, but in pure Java, you could go from the string in `String string = dc.getDirectory();` to a directory, then use [`File.list(FilenameFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list-java.io.FilenameFilter-) for an array of TIFF images. BTW - this has nothing to do with Swing, as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will try to do something out of it. Though I would be pretty happy if there was a solution with ImageJ...
And yeah you are right with swing, my bad. Thanks for the hint.